# Issues with setting up HTTPS on localhost with Nuxt 3

Tags: ssl, https, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to set up to run Nuxt 3 with HTTPS for localhost. I've looked at other guides and questions that were already asked online, but they all seem to be using older versions of Nuxt and for some reason, that way does not work anymore. For example, I've tried using [this](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config/#https) link as a reference on how to set up my *nuxt.config.ts* file, however, it's not working out for me.

When using the server property, I'm getting the error "server does not exist in type NuxtConfig", however, devServer seems to not give me any errors at least (still not working). Here's my
`nuxt.config.file`

```js
import { fileURLToPath } from "node:url"

export default defineNuxtConfig({
    css: ["~/assets/global.scss"],
    experimental: {
        reactivityTransform: true,
    },
    app: {
        head: {
            htmlAttrs: {
                lang: "en",
            },
        },
    },
    devServer: {
        https: {
            key: fileURLToPath(new URL("~/certs/localhost-key.pem", import.meta.url)),
            cert: fileURLToPath(new URL("~/certs/localhost.pem", import.meta.url)),
        },
    },
})
```

SSL certificate is created and self-signed using `mkcert`.

After I generate the SSL certificate and install everything and try to access https://localhost:3000, I get the error "SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG".

I'd really appreciate if someone could help me out with this. I've never done this before so not really sure what I am doing and it's taking a while already to solve.

Comment: Using webpack or vite? Check that one also: https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config/#https

Comment: @kissu using vite. Also, I believe your link is the same as the one that I've included in my post?

Comment: Oh right, I was mainly wondering if you should not replace `devServer` by `server`. Not sure which one is a typo but it used to be just `server` as far as I remember. Also because having certificates locally on production seems quite wrong to me.

Comment: Yeah from all the examples I've seen, everyone seems to be using `server`. If I try to use it in the Nuxt config file, I get the error "Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'server' does not exist in type 'NuxtConfig' ". 

Also, I'm not going to use self-signed certificates on production, it's for development only at the moment.

Comment: Maybe give a try to that one: https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/7477

Comment: It seems following this guide: https://www.storyblok.com/faq/setting-up-https-on-localhost-in-nuxt-3 works and sets up HTTPS to work for development. However, now I'm getting a `500 fetch failed ()` error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To anyone stumbling upon this and searching for a different approach.

Simply add,

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devServer: {
    https: {
      key: 'localhost-key.pem',
      cert: 'localhost.pem'
    }
  },
})
```

No imports, no file reads. Everything just works perfectly. However,

> You do need to add `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` environment variable

As of March 22, 2023, The documentation is still not updated but the code is forked and merged with the correct info. So, the docs is due updating only.

Comment: How to enable ssl for network ip or 127.0.0.1?

Comment: I've used your method, but on "npm run dev" i'm getting the following error, as per your answer, sounds as though you didn't need to create those files? - 

" ERROR  ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'localhost-key.pem' "

Answer (score 3):

It seems I managed to find a way to set up HTTPS on localhost in the end.

Here's how I did it:

First I followed this [short guide](https://www.storyblok.com/faq/setting-up-https-on-localhost-in-nuxt-3) to set up & self-sign the SSL certificate. I also changed `nuxt dev` from the `package.json` file to the following `nuxt dev --https --ssl-cert localhost.pem --ssl-key localhost-key.pem`.

However, this gave me a `500 fetch failed` error. This was solved by following this [thread](https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/7477), which basically stated that you need to add the `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` environment variable.

Now everything seems to be working perfectly!

Comment: nuxt 3 docs in regards of devServer and https seem completely broken / misleading at this moment. Kind of a bummer considering, it should be a stable release now.
+ nuxtConfig devServer options, filled out according to TS schema, seem to have no effect.
Your solution woked 